# Flyspell Not Working in AucTeX

Tags: auctex, flyspell

A while back flyspell stopped working for me in AucTeX.  I've been cleaning out my init.el file to see if I could fix the problem.  I can still do M-x flyspell-mode when in a .tex file.  But, I still can't get it to load automatically.  I've tried:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'turn-on-flyspell)
```

and

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook '(flyspell-mode t))
```

as suggested in other questions, but they do not work.  The portion of my init.el file that deals with LaTeX is listed below.  Though there are more lines in my init.el file, they don't seem like they would matter.

```
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t); PDF mode (rather than DVI-mode)


;;Indentation
(setq-default LaTeX-item-indent 0)  


;; " expands into csquotes macros (for this to work babel must be loaded after csquotes).
(setq LaTeX-csquotes-close-quote "}"
      LaTeX-csquotes-open-quote "\\enquote{")

;; LaTeX-math-mode http://www.gnu.org/s/auctex/manual/auctex/Mathematics.html
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode)


;;; RefTeX
;; Turn on RefTeX for AUCTeX http://www.gnu.org/s/auctex/manual/reftex/reftex_5.html
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)

(eval-after-load 'reftex-vars; Is this construct really needed?
  '(progn
     (setq reftex-cite-prompt-optional-args t); Prompt for empty optional arguments in cite macros.
     ;; Make RefTeX interact with AUCTeX, http://www.gnu.org/s/auctex/manual/reftex/AUCTeX_002dRefTeX-Interface.html
     (setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
     ;; So that RefTeX also recognizes \addbibresource. Note that you
     ;; can't use $HOME in path for \addbibresource but that "~"
     ;; works.
     (setq reftex-bibliography-commands '("bibliography" "nobibliography"     "addbibresource"))
;     (setq reftex-default-bibliography '("UNCOMMENT LINE AND INSERT PATH TO YOUR BIBLIOGRAPHY HERE")); So that RefTeX in Org-mode knows bibliography
     (setcdr (assoc 'caption reftex-default-context-regexps) "\\\\\\(rot    \\|sub\\)?caption\\*?[[{]"); Recognize \subcaptions, e.g. reftex-citation
     (setq reftex-cite-format; Get ReTeX with biblatex, see     https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31966/setting-up-reftex-with-biblatex-citation-commands/31992#31992
           '((?t . "\\textcite[]{%l}")
             (?a . "\\autocite[]{%l}")
             (?c . "\\cite[]{%l}")
             (?s . "\\smartcite[]{%l}")
             (?f . "\\footcite[]{%l}")
             (?n . "\\nocite{%l}")
             (?b . "\\blockcquote[]{%l}{}")))))

;; Fontification (remove unnecessary entries as you notice them)     http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2009-05/msg00236.html http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Fontification-of-macros.html
(setq font-latex-match-reference-keywords
      '(
        ;; biblatex
        ("printbibliography" "[{")
        ("addbibresource" "[{")
        ;; Standard commands
        ;; ("cite" "[{")
        ("Cite" "[{")
        ("parencite" "[{")
        ("Parencite" "[{")
        ("footcite" "[{")
        ("footcitetext" "[{")
        ;; ;; Style-specific commands
        ("textcite" "[{")
        ("Textcite" "[{")
        ("smartcite" "[{")
        ("Smartcite" "[{")
        ("cite*" "[{")
        ("parencite*" "[{")
        ("supercite" "[{")
        ; Qualified citation lists
        ("cites" "[{")
        ("Cites" "[{")
        ("parencites" "[{")
        ("Parencites" "[{")
        ("footcites" "[{")
        ("footcitetexts" "[{")
        ("smartcites" "[{")
        ("Smartcites" "[{")
        ("textcites" "[{")
        ("Textcites" "[{")
        ("supercites" "[{")
        ;; Style-independent commands
        ("autocite" "[{")
        ("Autocite" "[{")
        ("autocite*" "[{")
        ("Autocite*" "[{")
        ("autocites" "[{")
        ("Autocites" "[{")
        ;; Text commands
        ("citeauthor" "[{")
        ("Citeauthor" "[{")
        ("citetitle" "[{")
        ("citetitle*" "[{")
        ("citeyear" "[{")
        ("citedate" "[{")
        ("citeurl" "[{")
        ;; Special commands
        ("fullcite" "[{")))

(setq font-latex-match-textual-keywords
      '(
        ;; biblatex brackets
        ("parentext" "{")
        ("brackettext" "{")
        ("hybridblockquote" "[{")
        ;; Auxiliary Commands
        ("textelp" "{")
        ("textelp*" "{")
        ("textins" "{")
        ("textins*" "{")
        ;; supcaption
        ("subcaption" "[{")))

(setq font-latex-match-variable-keywords
      '(
        ;; amsmath
        ("numberwithin" "{")
        ;; enumitem
        ("setlist" "[{")
        ("setlist*" "[{")
        ("newlist" "{")
        ("renewlist" "{")
        ("setlistdepth" "{")
        ("restartlist" "{")))
```

Comment: Does `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)` help at all?  It shouldn't, but that's what I use (albeit I have it in `text-mode-hook` instead).  And can you verify that you see `flyspell-mode` if you `C-h v LaTeX-mode-hook RET`?  It looks like you're doing this, but always make sure to type `LaTeX-mode-hook` and not `latex-mode-hook`, as they are two different variables.

Comment: @dsedivec It doesn't do anything.  I still have to M-x flyspell-mode everytime I use AucTeX.